# Image overlay background opacity

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

i tried to make a image overlay.I will make that when i set the dic "overlay" to an image to apear a opacity above it.

I tried to make these code but it happens nothing

```
.gallery img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.overlay{
 opacity:1;
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
 background-size:cover;
 background:#000;
 }
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually define the overlay. You need to apply a `background-color` or `background-image` to your `.overlay`.

Comment: i forgot these, I aded but its nothing changed

Comment: Can you show me the full code of your gallery? Most likely a problem with the `<div>` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your HTML is structured but this should help you.
Based on your existing code..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="./img/random.png" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.gallery img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

**Note:** The opacity needs to have a value less than 1 to make it somewhat transparent.  Notice the 0.4 alpha/opacity setting in the CSS.

There are other ways to solution it, but without your code it's a little difficult to tailor it to your specific needs.